# Rotating an X,Y coordinate on the Cartesian Plane by Theta Degrees in C++

Tags: c++

In my code, I am creating a 2d scatter plot of points:

```
//Loop through all 13 objects
for (int playerEntity = 0; playerEntity < 13; playerEntity++) {

    //Obtain X and Y Value Offset from Scatter Plot's origin for each object
    int px = positionX[playerEntity] / 20;
    int py = positionY[playerEntity] / 20;

    //Establish X and Y origin in terms of the screen's pixels;
    int originX = 500;
    int originY = 1000;

    //Plot the scatter plot point in respect to the origin
    FillRGB(originX  + px , originY  + py);

}
```

How can I rotate points px and py around the graphs origin a certain amount of degrees? For instance, if I want to rotate the graph's points px and py 48 degrees around the origin, how can I do so? Any ideas?

Comment: You can use this formula: x = r * cos theta; y = r * sin theta. Here r is the radius

Comment: Perhaps this would be handy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix